# Reset value of select in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would reset a select rank with angular but in my case , that does not work. If i try this code with the case (just after) of $scope.projetColumn. It's good.

In my controller :

```
$scope.projetColumn = [
  {
     id: 1,
     group : "Backlog",
     name : " = 'Backlog (Stock)'"
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     group : "In Progress",
     name : "not in (New,'Backlog (Stock)',Closed)"
  }
];
```

And then if i call this function , it's OK the select is reset :

In my controller :

```
$scope.resetDropDown = function() {
    if(angular.isDefined($scope.projetAA)){
        delete $scope.projetAA;
    }
}
```

In my view :

`PROJET <select name="selectProjet" class="form-control"  ng-model="projetAA"     ng-change="getProjetColumns(projetAA,column)" ng-options="item as item.name for  item in projetColumn track by item.id"></select>`

`STATUT <select  name="selectColumn" class="form-control"  ng-model="column" ng-change="getStatut(column);" ng-options="item as item.name group by item.group for item in columnTab track by item.id"></select>`

BUT the problem, in my case, the $scope.projetColumn (ng-option of the first select ) changes everytime that i change ng-option of the second select. It is not static.

When i change the second select, i execute this code which update the first select with data from ($scope.projetColumn)

```
$scope.getStatut = function (columnTab) {
    $scope.makePromiseCards = cardsFactory.getListeAll(search);         
    $scope.makePromiseCards.then(function (value) {
       $scope.projetColumn = [];
       var objBase = {id: 0, name: ''};
       $scope.projetColumn.push(objBase);
       var cptG=1;

       $scope.cards.forEach(function(entry){
          entry.forEach(function(entry2){
             if((entry2.fields !== undefined) && findProjectInObject(entry2.fields.project.key,$scope.projetColumn) === -1) {
                 var obj = {id: cptG, name: entry2.fields.project.key};
                 $scope.projetColumn.push(obj);
                 cptG++;
             }
          });
       });
    });
 }
```

So , someone have an idea why the first select has always the same index and I can't reset the index at 0 even with the method of $scope.resetDropDown ?

Thank you by advance and sorry it's dificult to me to reproduce the bug with a plunker :/. I hope you will be able to understand my problem

Comment: `ng-model="column"` vs. `$scope.projetColumn`?

Comment: What is the problem ?  Sorry i dont understand.  You compare the ng-model from select (statut) ,  with the ng-options loop from select (projet). What's wrong ?

Comment: OK, I might have read too fast. But I see this column model defined nowhere.

Comment: You want to say that you dont see where i initialize $scope.columnTab for ng-options ? Its the same structure that $scope.projetColumn at the begin of my question.  Its a structure static in the controller. Is that your question or  i did not understand it ?

Comment: I very surprised,  for me,  its Just dirty,  but i replace  ng-model="projetAA" with ng-model="$root.projetAA" and in the controller  delete $rootScope. ProjetAA instead of $scope.projetAA and that work...  I dont understand because i have only one controller so its weird that i have to do à rootScope to communicate with view...

Comment: Too bad you can't make a plunk out of your code. Note: to simulate a $http promise, you can replace it with a $timeout, for example.

Comment: Sorry to be in late , so since the last message , i done a refactoring and also i change the select by this library : https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select. So , i don't know where was the problem but he  desapeared ... thank you for all ;)